# Copy specific type files from subfolders using a Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have many folders, some of which have subfolders. I want to find and copy to special directory all files of one type, for example .txt, from them. I use this script and it works, but it copies all folders on the way to my file too. How can I avoid this? I thought about deleting all empty folders after copying, but I'm sure that the more right way exists.

```
$folders = [IO.Directory]::GetDirectories("S:\other","*","AllDirectories")

Foreach ($dir in $folders) {
    Copy-Item -Path $dir -Filter *.txt -Recurse -Destination 'D:\FinishFolder'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to discover the files, then copy them 1 by 1:

```
Get-ChildItem S:\other -Filter *.txt -Recurse |Copy-Item -Destination 'D:\FinishFolder'
```

Comment: I will try this, thank you!